# How to call a Rust function that expects a double pointer to buffer

Tags: c, ffmpeg, rust

I'm trying to map the following ffmpeg function: http://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.0/group__lavc__parsing.html#ga0dd9af605377fcbb49fffd982672d377 to Rust code

```
int av_parser_parse2    (   AVCodecParserContext *      s,
        AVCodecContext *    avctx,
        uint8_t **      poutbuf,
        int *   poutbuf_size,
        const uint8_t *     buf,
        int     buf_size,
        int64_t     pts,
        int64_t     dts,
        int64_t     pos 
    )
```

Here's my Rust code sketch:

```
fn parse2(
    &self, 
    av_codec_context: CodecContext,
    poutbuf: &mut [u8],
    poutbuf_size: &mut i32,
    buf: &[u8],
    pts: i64,
    dts: i64,
    pos: i64,
) -> Result<i32, Error> {
    unsafe {// ptr::null(), ptr::null_mut()
        match av_parser_parse2(self.as_mut_ptr(),
        av_codec_context.as_mut_ptr(),
        poutbuf.as_mut_ptr(),
        poutbuf_size.as_mut_ptr(),
        buf.as_mut_ptr(),
        buf.len() as i32,
        pts,
        dts,
        pos
) {
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the `av_parser_parse2` generated by Rust's C bindings:

```
pub fn av_parser_parse2(
    s: *mut AVCodecParserContext,
    avctx: *mut AVCodecContext,
    poutbuf: *mut *mut u8,
    poutbuf_size: *mut libc::c_int,
    buf: *const u8,
    buf_size: libc::c_int,
    pts: i64,
    dts: i64,
    pos: i64,
) -> libc::c_int
```

I'm having problems in 2 arguments:

```
        poutbuf.as_mut_ptr(),
        poutbuf_size.as_mut_ptr(),
```

How can I make a double pointer? In ffmpeg the user would provide a pointer to an empty buffer and to a size, which would be ovewritten by the function `av_parser_parse2`. I think I don't want the `poutbuf: &mut [u8]`, `poutbuf_size: &mut i32,` arguments. Maybe I need to return a fresh new `Vec` for every `parse2` call? So the return value for `parse2` would be the tuple `Vec, i32`.

So I think I should take off `poutbuf` and `poutbuf_size` from the arguments, and call `av_parser_parse2` with something that will become the `Vec` to return. However, I cannot pass a `Vec` as a double pointer, because I do not know the size of the returned packet.

How can I deal with the returned buffer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understood from docs,

> `poutbuf` set to pointer to parsed buffer or NULL if not yet finished.

> `poutbuf_size` set to size of parsed buffer or zero if not yet finished.

they are output parameters so you don't need to specify them in input and it would be allocated by FFMPEG. I am unsure how it must be deallocated, maybe by `decode_frame(data, size);` used in example.

If I am right, it must be called somehow like this:

```
fn parse2<'a>(
    &'a self, 
    av_codec_context: CodecContext,
    buf: &[u8],
    pts: i64,
    dts: i64,
    pos: i64,
) -> (i32, Option<NonNull<[u8]>>) {
    let mut poutbuf: *mut u8 = ptr::null();
    let mut poutbuf_size: usize = 0;
    unsafe {
        let len = av_parser_parse2(self.as_mut_ptr(),
                av_codec_context.as_mut_ptr(),
                &mut poutbuf as *mut *mut u8,
                &mut poutbuf_size as *mut usize,
                buf.as_mut_ptr(),
                buf.len() as i32,
                pts,
                dts,
                pos
            );

        // Used pointer because I don't know who must deallocate this
        // If it must be deallocated by Rust, consider `Box<[u8]>`
        let poutbuf: Option<NonNull<[u8]>> = 
            if poutbuf::is_null(){ None }
            else {
                Some( NonNull::from(slice::from_raw_parts(poutbuf, poutbuf_size)))
            };
        (len, poutbuf)
    }
}
```

Comment: Returning `ManuallyDrop<Box<T>>` doesn't prevent the calling code from dropping the `Box` (for instance, by calling `ManuallyDrop::into_inner`). You shouldn't use `Box` at all for memory not allocated by Rust. Return `Option<NonNull<[u8]>>` instead.

Comment: As I see, all this methods of `NonNull<[u8]>` are available only on nightly https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/ptr/struct.NonNull.html#impl-2 ? Also, if user dropps thing which are marked as `ManuallyDrop`, he maybe know what it really does.

Comment: `NonNull::slice_from_raw_parts` is a convenience and it doesn't apply in this situation anyway. You can use [`ptr::slice_from_raw_parts_mut`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/ptr/fn.slice_from_raw_parts_mut.html) and [`NonNull::new`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/std/ptr/struct.NonNull.html#method.new). But `NonNull` is just an example -- the point is that `Box` is 100% the wrong choice here. A `Box` is allocated by Rust; exposing `Box` here is a lie that makes the API unsound.

Comment: @trentcl I edited my answer. Do you agree with edits?

Comment: This only works if `*poutbuf` is actually set to point into the `AVCodecParserContext`, which I'm not sure is correct. Even if that's so, it might need to take `&'a mut self` instead of `&'a self` depending on whether subsequent calls to `parse2` can invalidate earlier pointers. If you don't know where `*poutbuf` is pointed to, that means you're relying on the caller to know, and if they do the wrong thing it can mean UB. That's why I suggested `NonNull`, which makes *no* lifetime guarantees, and so the caller has to explicitly take responsibility for correctly using it with `unsafe`.

Comment: If `*poutbuf` *does* point into `*s`, another possibility might be to return `Option<&'a Cell<[u8]>>` or `Option<&'a [Cell<u8>]>` (if `AVCodecParserContext` is also non-`Sync`).